# How to make the server do things after some database actions?

Tags: php, sql, timestamp

The title might be a bit unclear. But I have this problem with my website. I have some data stored in a sql database, including a timestamp. But now I need to make some calculations with that data and send an email, after a certain duration after that timestamp. But how do I do this? Since my website and my database only contain static data...

So to be clear: I have a site on shared hosting with a database. In that database are items that all contain a timestamp value. Now I need the server to undertake an action for every item in the database on a certain duration after that item's timestamp, for example send a mail.

This is probably an easy question, but I have no clue what to look for...

EDIT: I think I have found a solution by using setcronjob.com , thanks!

Comment: Create a cron job that runs periodically. It does a database query to find the data that matches the timestamp criteria, and sends email.

Comment: Why do I get the impression that everybody's gotten the, well, wrong impression - `?`

Comment: @Fred-ii- cronjob is not the answer ?

Comment: @Dagon I'm under the impression the OP wants or needs to use a timediff *"after a certain duration after that timestamp"*

Comment: im thinking that's what the periodic cron job checks to decide if an email should be sent?

Comment: I don't know. Let's wait for the OP's feedback on comments/answers. So far, nothing. @Dagon

Comment: 3 close votes, he had better be quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a job every so often to figure out how old that timestamp is and then send the emails you need to send. But how to run the job?

- If you can run scheduled jobs on your hosting (ie, you own the machine/VM and are not on shared hosting) you can run these jobs every x days/hours/minutes/seconds. In Linux, look up cron jobs, and Windows look up Task Scheduler (I think)
- If you're on shared hosting it's more difficult. Maybe you can convert some of your static pages into dynamic pages that run these jobs? Depending on how long they take to run you might want to look at running these jobs in a new thread ([pthreads](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php)). You'll need to have pthreads installed for this on your hosting, so #1 - scheduled jobs - is definitely more preferable.

Comment: Yes, I'm on shared hosting so I don't own the machine... How can I create a dynamic page that runs the script without having to open the page in a browser?

Comment: The best way to do it is to use your users browsers to launch some XHR/ajax requests using javascript to the an API service on the server. This means your visitors can get pages just fine without adding any load to the page (look up XMLHttpRequest, or $.ajax if you're using jQuery). This does depend on you getting page visits at the frequency you need to be checking your database. If you can't depend on that you could look at some external polling service, but as virtual machines cost $5/10 a month it's probably easier to go for that and use cron.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a Cron task to search your database for every row with the timestamp near the current time. From that point, you can simply do your calculations and send the email.

Could you tell me more about that "certain duration after that timestamp"?

Answer (score 1):

Also, in the database you could setup a job that runs on a schedule to make the calculations and email the results.